# WSO2 BPS - BPMN API not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I'm trying to use the REST API for BPMN following the documentation, but even the most basic requests such as

https://localhost:9443/bpmn/repository/deployments
or
https://localhost:9443/bpmn/repository/process-definitions

return the following error

```
{"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;"}
```

I'm using BPS server 3.5.1 with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_77, as it was downloaded, with the only addition of a BPMN process to test its dashboard. The service is run as root (via sudo)

What can be done to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on postman and it works perfectly. Please choose the correct request type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE), if not the following error will be thrown on the server side:

> javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;

Comment: Hi, I tried again but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Using HttpRequester on Firefox I get the following log (which still confirms what I wrote in my first question):  
  
_GET ..../deployments  
Username: admin  
  
-- response --  
400 Bad Request  
....  
  
{"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;"}_

Also, please note that I get an **InternalServerErrorException** and not a **ClientErrorException**. Thanks